# Using css :hover with map() method only working on first element

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am creating an app in React and I'm building the menu using an array and the map() method.

I have my navigation buttons displaying correcting and when hovering over the button, the colour changes, however, the transition only works on the first button, when you hover over the other buttons only the colour changes.

Here is my code:

```
const buttons = ["Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3", "Button 4", "Button 5"];

{buttons.map((name) => (
              <NavButton
                key={name}
                onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(name)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(!name)}
                onClick={() => handleToggle(name)}
                className={classNames("george", {
                  // active: navButtonClicked === name && activeButton === true, //If you just want to make the clicked button have the class active
                  // active: activeButton === true, //If you want to make all buttons active
                  // hovered: hovered === name,
                })}
              >
                {name}
              </NavButton>
            ))}
```

CSS

```
const NavButton = styled.div`
  //Border
  border-radius: 100%;
  //Colour
  color: white;
  background: #3498db;
  //Positioning
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
  //Sizing
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  //Text
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  //Transitions
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
  &:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    transition-duration: 50ms;
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  &:nth-child(1) {
    //Positioning
    z-index: 2;
  }
  &.active :nth-child(2) {
    //Positioning
    transition-duration: 50ms;
    transform: translate3d(0, 85px, 0);
  }
  &.active :nth-child(3) {
    transition-duration: 100ms;
    transform: translate3d(0, 170px, 0);
  }
  &.active :nth-child(4) {
    transition-duration: 150ms;
    transform: translate3d(0, 255px, 0);
  }
  &.active :nth-child(5) {
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    transform: translate3d(0, 340px, 0);
  }
`;
```

Am i not understanding something correctly?

Comment: Only properties that have a numeric default can be animated without first instantiating their value. That means you need to have a `transform` property set not only on hover. Adding initial property should sort your issue, for example  `...transform: scale(1); transition: transform ease-out 200ms;`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I thought I did but when I went back to the code it's still not working. Do you have an example?

Comment: Change your `//Transitions` css from `transition: transform ease-out 200ms;` to `transform: scale(1); transition: transform ease-out 200ms; `

Comment: That what I thought you meant but that doesn't work? It changes colour but the transition only works on the first button. I think it has something to do with the translate3d or position absolute on the Navbutton. If I delete the absolute position on the Navbutton all the buttons work, as soon as I add that line again, the buttons won't work

Comment: Seems like you have found the problem ;)